# Bootstrap 5 dropdown stopped working after installing @popper/core

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I've been using Bootstrap 5 for a while not noticing something may not work.

Then I found a model requires @popper/core, not just popper.js.

I installed it and suddenly my dropdowns stopped working.

The context: I use the dropdown in my React JSX layout.

React 16.11.0
Bootstrap 5.1.3

Some code:

```
import Popper from '@popperjs/core';
import $ from 'jquery'; 
//import { Dropdown } from 'bootstrap'; <-- doesn't help
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';

...
<div className="dropdown">
  <button className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It started working after I removed the "flat" reference to the bootstrap:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
```

From here:
https://gitlab.com/simevo/dropdown/-/commit/624e010e7aaba574bbab4af431054d4c5e47e80e

Comment: For some reason, this worked for me too.

I changed `import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min'` to `import 'bootstrap'`.